# Why does curl return file name instead of file contents?

Tags: shell, rest, curl

I am trying to use curl in shell to retrieve a file from a server with authentication. When I make the request with a web browser (and with some REST clients), I get the file contents. With other REST clients, and with curl and wget, I just get the file name as the response.

Unfortunately I can't provide a reproducible example because of my job.

---

When I make the request with a browser, I type and enter my login information to:

```
www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/filepath/file.ext
```

This always works and I download the file - I've tried it in Opera, Firefox, and Chrome. Similarly, with the Firefox RESTClient extension, I use these settings:

```
Method: GET
URL: www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/filepath/file.ext
Authorization: Basic blablabla
```

This always works and I get the contents of the file as the response.

---

However, when I use (what I'm certain are) the same settings on Chrome's Advanced Rest Client, I just get the file name as the response.

```
Method: GET
URL: https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/filepath/file.ext
Authorization: Basic blablabla
```

I know the authorization isn't the problem - when I enter incorrect information I get a response telling me. The URLs are identical - I simply copy and paste between the windows. Firefox's RESTClient must be adding some additional option that Chrome's ARC isn't. Unfortunately I don't know how to see the raw requests being sent by the clients - being able to see them might let me solve my problem.

In the shell, I experience the same behavior

```
$ curl --user user:password https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/path/file.ext

"/path/file.ext"
```

When I use the --raw option, I get slightly different output:

```
$ curl --user user:password https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/path/file.ext --raw

10
"/path/file.ext"
0
```

The console always prints 2 additional blank lines after the 0. The first number always exactly matches the number of characters before the file extension, and the second is always 0. Does the 0 mean curl is receiving an empty file?

With wget, I get the same behavior:

```
$ wget --user user --password password https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/path/file.ext

--[[Time Stamp]]--  https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/filepath/file.ext
Resolving www.domain.com (www.domain.com)... 0.0.0.0
Connecting to www.domain.com (www.domain.com)|0.0.0.0|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Processed
Authentication selected: Basic realm="Basic realm"
Reusing existing connection to www.domain.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: ‘files@path=%2Fpath%2Ffile.ext’

     0K                                                        [[Download Speed]]=[[Download Time]]

[[Time Stamp]] ([[Download Speed]]) - ‘files@path=%2Fpath%2Ffile.ext’ saved [22]
```

The contents of the file 'files@path=%2Fpath%2Ffile.ext' are just

```
"/path/file.ext"
```

It was suggested I try `-qO`, since `-q` turns off console output and `-O` writes the ouput to a file. The resulting file just contains the name of the file.

```
$ wget --user user --password password -qO file.ext https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/path/file.ext

$ cat file.ext
"/path/file.ext"
```

The quotes are included as part of the file contents. I have also tried using `--ask-password` instead of `--password` and received identical results.

---

My guess is that there is some option for curl which I'm either missing or not using correctly. I've tried `-L, --location` and a few others from [this documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) since that seems most like what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't change the output in any way.

Comment: Try `wget --user user --password password -qO - http://www.address.com/path/to/file`. Also try a site without password, it may be a permission issue. On a side note, `wget` outputs to a file (with the name it's displaying) so try `cat file.ext` too, in the dir where you called `wget`.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. The resulting file just contains the quoted filepath. `wget google.com` works just fine. As does `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/make/make-3.75-3.76.diff.gz`. I'll have to ask about the permissions stuff - since the API is intended for us, we should have permission. But it's possible someone screwed up somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried `wget --ask-password ...`?

Comment: Have you dumped the actual request headers in these various cases? curl and wget can certainly do that. I would like to believe the firefox and chrome tools can also do that.

Comment: The REST server itself isn't checking and performing different tasks based on agent or something like that, is it? In some cases I've seen that to be a huge difference between using a rest client, browser, and curl.

Comment: @ShellFish I just tried it and got the same result. @brazilianldsjaguar I don't believe so. I've tried spoofing Firefox with `-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...'` but got the same result.

Comment: Pretty strange issue. On a side note: when using `wget -qO $link`, you need to add another dash after the last flag `wget -qO - $link` or it won't work. I'm just saying this because I noticed you included it in your question.

Comment: Another good way to 'troubleshoot' curl requests is to dump the response headers (using the `-D` tag) - that can give you the HTTP status code and other good tidbits of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the server was looking for a request header. The server thought I didn't want to accept the type of file it had. I needed to ask it:

```
curl --user user:password https://www.domain.com/path/to/api?path=/filepath/file.ext -H "Accept: application/app"
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, mime-types were my next best guess :D

Comment: Nice, glad you fixed it! Accept your own answer to help out people in the future!

Comment: I would now, but it takes 2 days before I can accept my own answer.